# How can I confirm that the default temporary directory is full and that is the reason my assembler isn't progressing the genome assembly process?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystem, root, disk-usage

My sincere apologies for writing a lengthy question; but I am stuck in this problem, and I am not an advanced Linux user.
I was running the CLC genomics workbench for my *de novo* assembly work. CLC Genomics workbench is a licensed software that has all the packages for de novo assembly of DNA sequence reads and downstream analysis of contigs. Morning, when I checked the progress, I had a warning message on the screen that said: “There is not enough space in the root directory”. As of now, a stage of the assembly called “Contig generation is progressing”, and the process seems stuck at 14%. It took about 24 hours to have progress by 1%, from 13%.

The root directory `/` in my system is mounted onto the /dev/sda2. When I checked the freespace was 0%. I found out that the `/var/log/error_log` file had consumed the majority of the disk space, and ~600 GB was freed upon deleting the file (but I observed that the same file was being generated and filled at a faster pace). When I read about the CLC server, it says that it takes a lot of disk space for temporary files. These temporary files are needed for analysis, and these temporary files are written to the system’s default temporary directory. By default temporary directory, I believe they meant `/tmp`. When I checked the `/tmp`, [I found a `FASTA` file, sized ~ 185 GB](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1coZer_mkhrGXOQKghVoDYoVN154M-hk0/view?usp=sharing).

When I checked the size of the `/tmp` by running the following command, [I got a result that says `/tmp` is of `174G`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mEeK22pALHZ9Dks2OqN5f9wH6sIwGgC9/view?usp=sharing).

[The Disk Usage Analysis shows this output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CPyzngnSvMM_wx548GZY9MqvWLJm4zei/view?usp=sharing):

[When I ran `df -h`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zp95N3lbR87mypLCZEBw6FqugwpNx26M/view?usp=sharing), the output shows that the collective size of all `tmpfs` amounts to ~174GB, but it looks like they haven’t been used to the full capacity (not more than 1%). As of writing this question, the `/dev/sda2` has a free space of 500GB. I am confused if the `/tmp` is saturated - and the assembler is not able to write any more temporary files -  that underlies the lack of progress in the assembly process. How do I figure it out and substantiate it?

Comment: It looks like your /tmp folder is not backed by an in-memory tmpfs but by your main disk partition, and neither of them seems to be close to running out of space in your screenshots. Maybe you can disable logging or reduce the log level of your application somehow, if that is the main part consuming disk space? The amount of I/O operations and bandwidth for logging might also be a bottleneck for performance. I have no knowledge about your specific application though.